# System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)

Tags: c#

when i publish my project with visual studio 2017 the publishing successful wth no error but when i open the exe file it stop with this error

```
Windows             : 10.0.17134.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
clr.dll             : 4.7.3221.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll           : 4.7.3056.0 built by: NET472REL1
dfshim.dll          : 10.0.17134.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)


System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)


 System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
         System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
```

System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)

```
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
```

System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)

```
 System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

how to solve it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/troubleshooting-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2017

Comment: i dont know what is the problem to use this lik... can u xplain for me?

Comment: So you installed application using the Setup.exe?  Are you running the application with same account you did the install?